# bootstrapping vuetify with a factory pattern

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, factory-pattern

I have been trying for some time to upgrade my app from vuetify 1.5 to 2, after a lot of thought I think the issue is that the way my app initializes causes the issue, I cannot put my finger on exactly what it is though, the issue is that when I run the app I get errors in the console that none of the vuetify components are recognized.
Attached is a screenshot of the error message. 
My `main.js` file:

```
import 'babel-polyfill' // IE support

import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import {localizationFactory} from "./localization";
import {apiFactory, apiPluginFactory} from './api/api';
import {storeFactory} from "./store/store";
import {configServiceFactory} from "./services/configService";

import {Services, Security, Utils} from 'em-common-vue';

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import {filtersFactory} from './filters/index';
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

const appsService = new Services.appsService(process.env);
const loginDetails = {
  loginHost: appsService.getLoginStorage()
};

Security.ServiceFactory(loginDetails).then($security => {

  Vue.config.productionTip = false;

  Vue.use(Utils.EventBusPlugin);
  Vue.use($security);

  var vInstance = new Vue();
  const $api = apiFactory(vInstance, $security);

  configServiceFactory($security, $api).then($config => {
    Vue.use($config);
    Vue.use(apiPluginFactory($api));

    // for now
    const store = storeFactory($api, null);

    Vue.use(VueI18n);

    filtersFactory($config.$service);

    localizationFactory($config.$service).then(messages => {

      const i18n = new VueI18n({
        locale: 'en', // set locale
        messages, // set locale messages
      });
      Vue.use(Vuetify);

      let vuetify =  new Vuetify({
        icons: {
          iconfont: 'mdiSvg',
        },
      });
      new Vue({
        router,
        store,
        i18n,
        vuetify,
        render: h => h(App),

        computed: {

          title: {
            set(val) {
              document.querySelector('title').innerText = val;
            },
            get(val) {
              return document.querySelector('title').innerText;
            }
          }
        },

        mounted() {
          if (!document.querySelector('title')) {
            let title = document.createElement('title');
            document.head.append(title);
          }

          this.title = this.$config.get().title;
        }
      }).$mount('#app')
    });
  });

}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);

  if (err.loginUrl) {
    const nextUrl = appsService.getLogin(window.location.href);
    window.location.href = nextUrl;
  } else { // for now
    alert(err);
  }
});
```

How might I change my code to load vuetify properly? Alternatively what might be a pattern that might work for my code?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

Replace `import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";` with `import Vuetify from "vuetify";`

Alternatively if you want to use [vuetify-loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader):

- Add *vuetify-loader* to your project (if already present, update it)
- If you're using webpack directly add the `vuetify-loader` plugin to your webpack plugins:

```
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');
exports.plugins.push(new VuetifyLoaderPlugin());
```

- If you used `@vue/cli` to setup your project, you can use the [`configureWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) option in `vue.config.js` to add the plugin:

```
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
    ]
  }
}
```

### Why?

*vuetify* comes in two "flavors":

#### [A-la-carte](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte)

All vuetify components will **not** be directly required, but only loaded when you explicitly import them.
This greatly reduces your final package size, since you only include the parts of the vuetify framework that you're actually using.

You're using *A-la-carte* if you're importing vuetify from `vuetify/lib`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";
Vue.use(Vuetify);
const vuetify = new Vuetify({ /* ... */});
new Vue({vuetify}).$mount('#root');
```

The downside of a-la-carte is that you need to manually import each vuetify component you want to use:

```
import {VIcon} from "vuetify/lib";
export default {
  name: 'foo-component',
  components: { VIcon },
  template: '<v-icon>user</v-icon>'
};
```

To make this less a hassle, you can either:

- use `vuetify-loader`, it will automatically add those imports for you if you set it up correctly.
- globally load components you use a lot:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify, { VLayout } from 'vuetify/lib';
// globally register v-layout.
// now you don't need to import it in every component that uses it
Vue.use(Vuetify, { components: { VLayout } });
```

#### Normal Mode

If you import *vuetify* directly, it'll automatically load all its components for you and is ready to use without further configuration:

```
// not a-la-carte, will load all vuetify components
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify"; // **not** /lib
Vue.use(Vuetify);
const vuetify = new Vuetify({ /* ... */});
new Vue({vuetify}).$mount('#root');
```

Comment: Ok so what you are suggesting seems to help, although the reason that I am importing `vuetify/lib` is for tree shaking. In terms of `vuetify-loader` I have it! from my package.json `    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"` I dont have direct access to the webpack config but you can see my vue.config.js here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555348/getting-error-when-trying-to-upgrade-to-vuetify-2-0

Comment: @Michael It looks like you aren't adding `vuetify-loader` as a webpack plugin in your `vue.config.js`. Do you have a vue cli plugin installed for it?

Comment: @Michael I added an example to the top of my answer how you can add `vuetify-loader` to your `vue.config.js`, hopefully that solves your problem :)

Comment: I do have the vue cli plugin, I did try adding into the webpack config and got this:
`Module parse failed: Identifier 'installComponents' has already been declared (31:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
` which means the loader is being called twice...

Comment: @Michael which version of `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify` do you use? if you're using the cli plugin, you don't need to manually add `vuetify-loader` in your `vue.config.js`, the plugin will do it for you

Comment: "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.10.0",
Despite that it is not loading it properly since none of the components are detected :-( that is unless I load the entire vuetify, or I may resolve to manual a-la-carte

Comment: @Michael it should be `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify`, which version of that plugin are you using?